# Select all Checkboxes in a Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to select all the checkboxes in a gridview i have running on my page, i'm using JQuery and Javascript for the function but the javascript doesn't seem to work .
I've tried the same script on a normal table and it worked but it doesn't seem to work on the checkboxes i've added to my gridview.
Can you guys help me with this issue.
Here's the code for the page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SMSWebMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Search.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation ="false" Inherits="SMSWebApp.Views.Search" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


   $(function () {
       $("#tblChck [id*=chkHeader]").click(function () {
           if ($(this).is( ":checked")) {
               $("#gvData [id*=cbSelect2]").attr("checked", "checked");
           } else {
               $("#gvData [id*=cbSelect2]").removeAttr("checked");
           }
       });
       $("#gvData [id*=cbSelect2]").click(function () {
           if ($("#gvData [id*=cbSelect2]").length == $("#gvData [id*=cbSelect2]:checked").length) {
               $("#tblChck [id*=chkHeader]").attr("checked", "checked");
           } else {
               $("#tblChck [id*=chkHeader]").removeAttr("checked");
           }
       });
   });
```

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server"> 

<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" EnableViewState="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"> 

</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <div id="contectcontainer">
        <div class="content">
            <br />
            <br />
            <center>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblapo" Text=" Apolice" CssClass="label_style3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TBoxApo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text=" Recibo" CssClass="label_style3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TBoxRec" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
             <br />
             <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text=" Mediador" CssClass="label_style3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TBoxMed" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text=" Tomador" CssClass="label_style3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TBoxTom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
             <br />
             <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text=" Veiculo" CssClass="label_style3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TBoxVeic" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>
                <table id="tblChck" runat="server">
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                         <asp:CheckBox id="chkHeader"  Text="Selecione Todos"  runat="server"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </table>
            <br />
             <br />
            <br />
      <asp:GridView id="gvData" CssClass="table-design" runat="server" SkinID="Fun" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div style="padding:10px;margin-left:10px">
                   Sem Dados !!!
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

             <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:checkbox id="cbSelect2" CssClass="gridCB" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Apolice" DataField="Apolice" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recibo" DataField="Recibo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Agente_Mediador" DataField="Agente_Mediador" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cliente_Tomador" DataField="Cliente_Tomador" /> 
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Veiculo" DataField="Veiculo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data" DataField="Data" /> 
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="Id" /> 
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>




             <br />
             <br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="TruBtn_Click" Text="Pesquisar" />
```

```
</div>
</div>
    </div>
 </form>
</asp:Content>
```

And the backend

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SMSWebApp.SupprotClasses;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace SMSWebApp.Views
{
  public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {


        }
    }




    SqlConnection msqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);

    public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        // open the connection
        if (msqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            msqlConnection.Open();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        // close the connection

        if (msqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            msqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }



    public void TruBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TBoxApo.Text == "" && TBoxMed.Text == "" && TBoxRec.Text == "" && TBoxTom.Text == "" && TBoxVeic.Text == "")
        {
            string script = "alert(\"Enter any value!\");";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);

            TBoxApo.Focus();

        }
        else
        {
            Btn_Click4( );

        }
    }

    protected void Btn_Click3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFilePath path = new SaveFilePath();

        List<string> batata = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < gvData.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)gvData.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("cbSelect2");
            if (chkb.Checked)
            {

                string seven = gvData.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text;
                int Id = Convert.ToInt32(seven);

                string fullpath = path.GetFullPath4(Id);
                Response.Write("<br>" + fullpath);
                batata.Add(fullpath);



            }
        }
        var archive = Server.MapPath("~/archive.zip");
        var temp = Server.MapPath("~/temp");



        if (System.IO.File.Exists(archive))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(archive);
        }
        //  Directory.EnumerateFiles(temp).ToList().ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f));
        Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(temp).ToList().ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Delete(f));

        batata.ForEach(f => System.IO.File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(temp, Path.GetFileName(f))));

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(temp, archive);
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= archive.zip");
        Response.TransmitFile(archive);
    }




    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();

    }



    public void Btn_Click4()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Constring"].ConnectionString);
            OpenConnection();
            SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcommand.Connection = sql;

            string apolice = TBoxApo.Text;
            string recibo = TBoxRec.Text;
            string mediador = TBoxMed.Text;
            string tomador = TBoxTom.Text;
            string veiculo = TBoxVeic.Text;


            // Pesquisas com a Apolice



            if (TBoxApo.Text != "")
            {

                sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%'";

                if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%'";
                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%'  and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";

                }

                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                }

                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Cliente_Tomador like '%" + tomador + "%' and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Cliente_Tomador like '%" + tomador + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                }
                else if (TBoxApo.Text != "" && TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Apolice like '%" + apolice + "%' and Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%' and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                }
            }

            // Pesquisas com o Recibo

            else
            {
                if (TBoxRec.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%'";

                    if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";

                    }

                    else if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                    }

                    else if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%' ";

                    }

                    else if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";
                    }

                    else if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";
                    }

                    else if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%'and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";
                    }

                    else if (TBoxRec.Text != "" && TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where  Recibo like '%" + recibo + "%' and Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";
                    }
                }

                // Pesquisas com o Mediador

                else if (TBoxMed.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Agente_Mediador like '%" + mediador + "%'";

                    if (TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%' ";

                    }
                    else if (TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Agente_Mediador like '%" + mediador + "%' and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                    }
                    else if (TBoxMed.Text != "" && TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Agente_Mediador like'%" + mediador + "%'and Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                    }
                }


                // Pesquisas com o Tomador

                else if (TBoxTom.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Cliente_Tomador like '%" + tomador + "%'";

                    if (TBoxTom.Text != "" && TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                    {
                        sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Cliente_Tomador like'%" + tomador + "%'and Veiculo like'%" + veiculo + "%' ";

                    }
                }

                // Pesquisas com o Veiculo


                else if (TBoxVeic.Text != "")
                {
                    sqlcommand.CommandText = "select Apolice,Recibo,Agente_Mediador,Cliente_Tomador,Veiculo,Data,Id from UniDownTeste.dbo.DownUni where Veiculo like '%" + veiculo + "%'";


                }


            }

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            gvData.DataSource = ds;
            gvData.DataBind();

        }
        finally { CloseConnection(); }

    }







}
```

}

Here's the rendered HTML
[image: Rendered Page]

And here's the Console when executing

[image: Console Page]

Comment: GridView checkboxes render with ajax?

Comment: Please show your result html!

Comment: the problem is in your html, when render your table, you probably have a disorder when drawing table, show your result html code to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new project and used your code. The reason why your JS is not working is because you relay on Id of server controls, e.g:

```
#tblChck, #gvData
```

They will have different Ids in the client browser. It's how ASP.NET works to prevent duplication of Id. If you have a master page all serwer controls in content page will have a prefix added to Id like "MainContent_". In order to make your JS to work you need to change JQ selector to something like `table[id*=tblChck]` or you can add a css class and select by it.

To be completly clear in order to make your code to work I had to change JS to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("table[id*=tblChck] [id*=chkHeader]").click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("table[id*=gvData] [id*=cbSelect2]").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("table[id*=gvData] [id*=cbSelect2]").removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });
        $("table[id*=gvData] [id*=cbSelect2]").click(function () {
            if ($("table[id*=gvData] [id*=cbSelect2]").length == $("table[id*=gvData] [id*=cbSelect2]:checked").length) {
                $("table[id*=tblChck] [id*=chkHeader]").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("table[id*=tblChck] [id*=chkHeader]").removeAttr("checked");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I reference JQuery in the master
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")%>"></script>
but it doesn't seem to be interfering with the script i referenced in this page.I've tried the same function with the same script references on a normal static table and it worked, it shared the same master page. I've posted both the rendered HTML and the console on Internet Explorer. Thanks for helping

Comment: By rendered html I meant html source view not the browser screen ;)

Comment: Sorry can you specify, cause all the source code for this specific page is in the question, should i post the code for the master page as well.

Comment: @Rob thx for your guidance, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.chkHeader').click(function(event) { 
           if(this.checked) { // check select status
               $('.gridCB').each(function() { 
                $('.chkHeader').each(function() { 
                  this.checked = true;
                });
                   this.checked = true;           
               });
           }else{
               $('.gridCB').each(function() { 
                $('.chkHeader').each(function() { 
                  this.checked = false;
                });                
                   this.checked = false; 
               });         
           }
       });
```

add class in your .chkHeader main checkbox
like :->

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkHeader" class="chkHeader"  Text="Selecione Todos"  runat="server"  />
```